# Which is the correct way of reporting?

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

Which one is the correct way to report a past episode?

1. They wanted that Joe must not be around when they go shopping.
2. They wanted that Joe must not be around when they went shopping.

Answer (score -2):

They wanted Joe not to be around when they go shopping.

The that here is unnecessary. For example in a simpler sentence, "I wanted to eat ice cream." instead of "I wanted that I eat ice cream."

Comment: You should always include reasons why you consider the selected sentence is correct.

Comment: Added an example that hopefully explains the usage.